TinyMCE 7.3.0 - DOM error on editor destroy
I integrated TinyMCE 7.3.0 in a web application (simil single-page) that loads fragments via Jquery (ajax calls or load method). The editor is inside a page that permits user to compose a text for a mail, loads via Jquery .load() correctly but when the user abandons the page loading another page (always via .load() method) gets a Javascript DOM error (invalid character). The same error happens if destroy() or remove() are called explicitly.
In a simple page I can't reproduce the error, thus something in the page layout / html is breaking the library.
The load seems to succeed (the new page content is pulled from the server) but Javascript throws an exception about a DOM invalid character. On a debug session the problem is on row 1174 (tinymce.js from DEV zip version 7.3.0)
const rawSet = (dom, key, value) => { 
if (isString(value) || isBoolean(value) || isNumber(value)) 
{ 
dom.setAttribute(key, value + ''); 
} 
else 
{ 
console.error('Invalid call to Attribute.set. Key ', key, ':: Value ', value, ':: Element ', dom); throw new Error('Attribute value was not simple'); 
} 
};


where both key and value are empty strings (causing the exception).
Adding a further control over value content the problem is not detected and the pages load correctly.
const rawSet = (dom, key, value) => 
{ 
if (isString(value) || isBoolean(value) || isNumber(value)) 
{ 
**if (value != "")** 
dom.setAttribute(key, value + ''); 
} 
else 
{ 
console.error('Invalid call to Attribute.set. Key ', key, ':: Value ', value, ':: Element ', dom); throw new Error('Attribute value was not simple'); 
} 
};

I don't understand if it's a library bug or a malformed HTML code that creates this behaviour.
